# How to inject DAO bean in tapestry (with Spring JDBC)

Tags: spring-jdbc, tapestry

I am using Spring-JDBC with Tapestry and not able to inject DAO bean which I have defined in Spring.xml. Normally we use applicationContext.getBean, but in tapestry I am not able to find such option. Please guide me how I can inject DAO bean to use it in my code. Below is kind of code I am having:

```
Class ABC{
with private members, getters,setters and constructors
} 

Class abcDAO{
private JdbcTemplate template
//getter and setter for jdbc template

//a method which will extract data using Rowmapper
public Set<ABC> getAll(){
//override mapRow method
}
}


I want to use getAll method in a class which will process extracted data. Please help me where should I inject abcDAO bean with below line:

@Inject private abcDAO abcDao;

Thanks in advance!!!
```

Comment: which tapestry version do you use? Have you added the tapestry5-jquery lib to your project?

Comment: Take a look at [the Tapestry-Spring integration guide](https://tapestry.apache.org/integrating-with-spring-framework.html)

Comment: @LakiGeri I m using Tapestry 5.2.0

Comment: @Jaims Yes I went through this doc. actually I am getting "org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject does not exist" when I inject DAO bean using method given in this doc. Am I missing something? I want to inject DAO bean in a normal java class and not the pages or component class.

Comment: Regular Java POJOs are not managed by the Tapestry IOC-Container by default. You could create a service of the class or place it inside a package called `base` on the same level as `pages` and `components`. e.g. `com.example.tapproject.base.DaoUser.java`. This class can inject the `Spring` service (if configured according the integration guide). But the `DaoUser` class should be injected as well. Not created with the `new` keyword.